# gpfs file access through Java API/Python

Tags: biginsights

I am new to IBM-GPFS.
As we can access HDFS via Java API, python scripting.
Is there any similar way to access GPFS files?
Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 5):

GPFS is an actual file system (e.g. a VFS on Linux). It does not require an special APIs to access its files. Simply use the open, read, and write functions supported by your programming environment.